# Can't update Model.Algorithm in ASP.NET Core MVC, always switches back to Caesar

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a Webpage that encrypts the input inside Model.Plaintext and outputs it. My problem is, that after i submit the Model.Algorithm, it always swtiches back to Caesar Cipher. I want it to stay at the currently selected algorithm until i pick another one. Any idea how to implement this behaviour?

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="plainText">Plain Text:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plainText" name="plainText" value="@Model.PlainText">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="algorithm">Algorithm:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="algorithm" name="algorithm">
            <option value="caesar">Caesar Cipher</option>
            <option value="vigenere">Vigenere Cipher</option>
            <option value="railfence">Rail Fence Cipher</option>
            <option value="sha256">sha256 Cipher</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Encrypt</button>
</form>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Cipher))
{
    <hr />
    <h2>Encrypted Text:</h2>
    <p>@Model.Cipher</p>
}
```

Ive tried saving the state inside the Controller but had no success, since the change happens in the .cshtml

Comment: As mentionned by @HasaniH, you need to add a default selected value. Since none are provided, the app takes the first available option value; hence displaying `caesar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to dynamically set `selected` on the desired `option`. Replacing the `select` in your code with something like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="algorithm" name="algorithm">
    @{
        foreach (var option in options)
        {
            if (option ==  Model.Algorithm)
            {
                <option value="@option" selected="selected">@option</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@option">@option</option>
            }
        }
    }
</select>
```